# Why is it instantly going to 11th column when I'm trying to find position?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have ran into a problem where I run the code and when it gets to nested loop the c aka column just instantly goes to 11.

```
       private void UpdatePlayerPiecePosition(Player player, int totalRoll, Property[,] gameBoardProperties, int maxColumns)
       {
           if (player.Piece != null)
           {
               int newPosition = (player.CurrentPosition + totalRoll) % (gameBoardProperties.GetLength(0) * maxColumns);

               (int row, int col) = FindIndicesForPosition(gameBoardProperties, newPosition);

               player.CurrentPosition = newPosition;

               Grid.SetColumn(player.Piece, col);
               Grid.SetRow(player.Piece, row);
           }
       }

       private (int, int) FindIndicesForPosition(Property[,] gameBoardProperties, int newPosition)
       {
           int row = -1, col = -1;

           for (int c = 0; c < gameBoardProperties.GetLength(0); c++)
           {
               for (int r = 0; r < gameBoardProperties.GetLength(1); r++)
               {
                   if (gameBoardProperties[c, r] != null && gameBoardProperties[c, r].Position == newPosition)
                   {
                       row = r;
                       col = c;
                       break;
                   }
               }
           }

           return (row, col);
       }
```

I was thinking the problem would be else were in my code, but I couldn't find any problem with code which could link to the nested loop to work like that.

Comment: did you debug your code?

Comment: @RandRandom yes I did, well I think soo, the nested loop goes good the 1st time, like checking if the [0,0] array is the position, but then it goes to [1,11] and starts checking each column but only at the last row (I changed up a bit of the for loop so its more correct)

Comment: try to edit this sample with your issue: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jCADTi - it is hard to know where your problem may be, because your code works as I would expect

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a confusion between rows and columns in your `FindIndicesForPosition` method. The variable names `c` and `r` might be causing confusion regarding rows and columns.

Try swapping the `c` and `r` variables in your `FindIndicesForPosition` method.

```
private (int, int) FindIndicesForPosition(Property[,] gameBoardProperties, int newPosition)
{
    int row = -1, col = -1;

    for (int c = 0; c < gameBoardProperties.GetLength(0); c++)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < gameBoardProperties.GetLength(1); r++)
        {
            if (gameBoardProperties[c, r] != null && gameBoardProperties[c, r].Position == newPosition)
            {
                row = c; // Swap row and column assignments
                col = r; // Swap row and column assignments
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return (row, col);
}
```

Comment: thank you for noticing that. Accidentally swapped them around, still the number for the inner for loop magically goes to 11. I'll try to debug the code more.